# origin of the word "de" in the name of Tycho de Brahe, Danish astronomer

Tags: etymology

I am conducting a little research about the origin of the word "de" in a version of a name of the Danish astronomer "Tycho Brahe", namely: "Tycho de Brahe".

Here is what I have: in the Danish language there is no word "de". I was able to find it in Spanish, Portuguese, French, Italian and Romanian.

A note: similar words also exist: "von" in German or "van" in Dutch.

These words are used to indicate a place of birth, belonging to a noble origin or just a part of a last name.

Question: What is the origin of the version "Tycho de Brahe" of Brahe's full name?

Hypothesis: a historian from the mentioned list of countries started to use it and it become a wide-spread mistake since then.

Thank you.

Photo of his residency in Prague:

[image]

Comment: The [Brahe family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahe) belongs to the Danish and Swedish nobility, so the *de* could be a nobility marker. Unsourced, therefore only a comment.

Comment: My current hypothesis is that Mr. Brahe wanted to feel more noble in Prague, where the noble people often had "von XXX", in case they were noble. So he started to call himself "de Brahe" to emphasize that he is of noble origin, although in Denmark noble people didn't do that. Just a hypothesis.

Comment: @Jan But people _did_ do that in Denmark as well (natively with _af_). Tycho himself, however, never used it. According to [this article on the name](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/143823/ActaCarolinae_046-2005-3_6.pdf), the spurious _de_ didn’t appear until the 1800s. As to why it appeared, goodness knows – perhaps the article speculates on that (I only just scanned the first part of it quickly).

Comment: I think this "de" added to Tycho Brahe  is only found in Czechia. If you are Czech, please go to Czech wikipedia about him and on the first line you will find *někdy uváděný **chybně** jako „Tycho de Brahe“* - "sometime **mistakenly** mentioned as Tycho de Brahe". The article by Janus above has more detail. I just wanted to stress it is mostly found in our country.

Comment: Cross-posted https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13802/origin-of-the-word-de-in-the-name-of-danish-astronomer-tycho-de-brahe Please do not post the same question to multiple SE sites. Choose one.

Comment: @Vladimir F: linguists and historians may have different point of view that the other ones don't have.

Comment: @Jan That is possible, but is a poor form here, really. Many people frequent multiple sites anyway. You should at least link the other question and always taylor the question to the site if you really want different point of view.

Comment: @Jan please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu You can notice some dissenting voices there, but they are quite a minority.